# How do I fix my code so that it is automated?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, recursion

I have the below code that takes my standardized `.txt` file and converts it into a JSON file perfectly. The only problem is that sometimes I have over 300 files and doing this manually (i.e. changing the number at the end of the file and running the script is too much and takes too long. I want to automate this. The files as you can see reside in one `folder/directory and I am placing the JSON file in a different`folder/directory, but essentially keeping the naming convention standardized except instead of ending with `.txt` it ends with .json but the prefix or file names are the same and standardized. An example would be: `CRAZY_CAT_FINAL1.TXT, CRAZY_CAT_FINAL2.TXT` and so on and so forth all the way to file 300. How can I automate and keep the file naming convention in place, and read and output the files to different folders/directories? I have tried, but can't seem to get this to iterate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import glob
import time
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import json

    csvfile = open(r'C:\Users\...\...\...\Dog\CRAZY_CAT_FINAL1.txt', 'r')
    jsonfile = open(r'C:\Users\...\...\...\Rat\CRAZY_CAT_FINAL1.json', 'w')
    
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
    jsonfile.write(out)

****************************************************************************
I also have this code using the python library "requests". How do I make this code so that it uploads multiple json files with a standard naming convention? The files end with a number...

    import requests

#function to post to api

    def postData(xactData):
        url = 'http link'
        headers = {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Content-Length': str(len(xactData)),
           'Request-Timeout': '60000'
        }
        return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=xactData)

    #read data
    f = (r'filepath/file/file.json', 'r')
    data = f.read()
    print(data)

    # post data
    result = postData(data)
    print(result)
```

Comment: maybe you should use `os.listdir(r"C:\Users\...\...\...\Dog\")` or `glob.glob(r:\Users\...\...\...\Dog\*.txt')` to get all filenames in folder and later use `for`-loop to process all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
from glob import glob
import csv
import json
import os

INPATH r'C:\Users\...\...\...\Dog'
OUTPATH = r'C:\Users\...\...\...\Rat'
for csvname in glob(INPATH+'\*.txt'):
    jsonname = OUTPATH + '/' + os.basename(csvname[:-3] + 'json')
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(csvname,'r'))
    json.dump( list(reader), open(jsonname,'w') )
```

Comment: How do I send the file to a different path using the OUTPATH variable? I didn't see it used above.

Comment: I also added in another problem that I couldn't solve above -- maybe you can help?

Answer (score 2):

Use `f-strings`?

```
for i in range(1,301):
    csvfile = open(f'C:\Users\...\...\...\Dog\CRAZY_CAT_FINAL{i}.txt', 'r')
    jsonfile = open(f'C:\Users\...\...\...\Rat\CRAZY_CAT_FINAL{i}.json', 'w')
```

Comment: your going to have to give a little more information on what happened buddy. I'm not a mind reader, though I wish I was :)